# Can pagerControls have onclick events?

Tags: xpages, pager

I've got a dynamic view that totals what's displayed on the screen using a viewScope variable and I want to have it reset my viewScope variable. It doesn't and it appears not to be executing any script I put in there.

```
<xp:pager partialRefresh="true" id="upperPager"
for="viewRowRepeat" styleClass="tsDynamicViewPager" pageCount="8"
alwaysCalculateLast="true">
<xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl4" type="First">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewRowRepeat">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:dBar.info("pagerControl4 clicked");
clearColumnTotals();}]]></xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("Clicked!");]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:pagerControl>
    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl5" type="Group">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:dBar.info("pagerControl5 clicked");
clearColumnTotals();}]]></xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("Clicked!");]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:pagerControl>
    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl6" type="Last">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
            submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:dBar.info("pagerControl6 clicked");
clearColumnTotals();}]]></xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("Clicked!");]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:pagerControl>
</xp:pager>
```

Needless to say, I don't know if I've coded it incorrrectly or if there isn't supposed to be any onclick event for pagerControls. I know the IDE doesn't show one for pagers themselves.

Comment: If you can't get the onlick to work then maybe you could make a clientside script that does an ajax call when the pager button is clicked in order to direct to an XAgent that updates your viewScope variable and redirects back to the current page.  Seems like a lot of trouble, but if that is what you need to do...

Comment: But, the trouble is, I can't get anything to run onclick for the pagercontrol. Nothing in CSJS or SSJS.

Comment: You can with jQuery if the pager button has a class associated with it. For example, put it is a span with class of "pleaseWork", then in jQuery, select all buttons inside all spans with class of .pleaseWork (you can get very granular with jQuery selectors), and then have a function that runs your ajax call when the button is clicked.  Load this when the page loads.  It has to be possible, because once on the page all the controls are just part of the DOM.  Hint: First get it working by creating an alert("you clicked me") message when clicked, then work on the ajax piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your pager controls with a Dojo `onclick` event to execute client side code when pager control is clicked:

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        dojo.query(".xspFirst").forEach(function(node) {
          dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function() { 
               alert("First clicked");
          });
        });
        dojo.query(".xspGroup").forEach(function(node) {
          dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function() { 
               alert("Group clicked");
          });
        });
        ...
    ]]>
    </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Classes rendered for pager controls are "xsp" + type like "xspFirst", "xspGroup" and "xspLast". Use this classes to get the controls.